# WSO2 ESB - Rampart Password Callback class - WSPasswordCallback cannot be cast

Tags: wso2, ws-security, wss4j, wso2-esb

I want to to invoke a secured backend service in WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 with rampart configuration and [Password Callback class](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/ws-security-signing-of-messages)

```
package com.yenlo.wso2.services;
import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PWCBHandler implements CallbackHandler {

public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
    WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0]; 

    // set the password for our message.
    pc.setPassword("YENLO_TEST");       

   }
}
```

When i call the proxy service this error occurs:

```
org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback cannot be cast to org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback
```

I have compiled my source code with wss4j 1.6.17 and 1.5.12. Nothing's Changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new callbackhandler project from scratch and got it working with a few sidenodes: 
- I've used the following dependency in the main pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.11</version>
</dependency>
```

I put the resulting '.jar' in repository/components/lib. Also I removed the .jar from repository/components/dropins when redeploying to be sure(ESB creates a file there during startup when processing the .jar)

I've put the entire project [here](https://bitbucket.org/Carpentidge/callbackhandler/src/master/). Build using 'mvn clean package'.

Good luck! I'd like to hear back if you succeeded!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the available version of wss4j inside "wso2esb-5.0.0/repository/components/plugins" folder. It looks like you are using a different version in the compile time, that may lead to this kind of issue.

Try to use wss4j with the following dependency version when compiling.

```
version=1.5.11.wso2v14
groupId=org.apache.ws.security.wso2
artifactId=wss4j
```

Comment: Nothing's Changed. I have downloaded wss4j-1.5.11.wso2v14.jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.security.wso2/wss4j/1.5.11.wso2v14

Comment: How do you compile your source ? Are you using maven or different method ? What is your java version?

Comment: I have used maven. my java version is 1.8.0_181

Comment: my pom file: 
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security.wso2</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.11.wso2v14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

   
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>wso2-public</id>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>